# Fastreport : Detail Data: limit the number of records

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I need to generate a two-sided report. In Detail Data, In the first page I need to limit the number of records to 15, and in the second page I need to limit the number of records to 8.

- **Page 1** : 15 records.
- **page 2** : 08 records.

How to do it please?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a fastreport script

```
    var np : integer = 0;   // variable de script
 
procedure MasterData1OnAfterPrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var rec : integer;
begin
  np:=np+1;
  if (np=7) then engine.newpage;
  if (np=11) then begin
    np:=0;
    engine.newpage;
  end;
end;
 
begin
 
end.
```